# Trying to pass a value into a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Building a small search app using Elasticsearch and AngularJS. 2 pages, home and results page. Everything is working except... I have this custom search directive that I'm trying to pass the value of a service into. The service is a variable that is bound to ngModel in my controller.

How can I pass the value of searchTerms from home to the results page?

My service

```
.service('queryService', function() {
    var searchTerms;
    this.searchTerms = null;
```

I pass my service into the controller and set it to $scope

```
$scope.searchTerms = queryService.searchTerms;
```

I then $watch it for changes

```
$scope.$watch('searchTerms', function() {
queryService.searchTerms = $scope.searchTerms;
```

});

My directive looks like this

```
.directive('searchResults', ['queryService', function(queryService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        //priority: 1001,
        scope: {
            searchTerms: "=",//ngModel
            results: "=",
            websiteUrls: "=",
            suggestions: "&",
            search: "&"
        },
        templateUrl: 'search/search-results.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }
}]);
```

My search input:

```
<input type="text" name="q" ng-model="searchTerms" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg" id="search-input" uib-typeahead="query for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search($item)" autofocus>
```

I have 2 way data binding working, but no autocomplete(Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead) or search functionality. I'm pretty sure something is suppose to go in the link function, just not sure what... still learning AngularJS directives.

NOTE: Everything works if I perform a search from the results page.

**More Info** So basically what I'm trying to do is a user enters a search Term on the home page. searchTerms is my ngModel. I'm using AngularJS UI Bootstrap Typeahead for autocomplete functionality(as can be seen on the input tag). I have a queryService that initiates searchTerms to null and the queryService is DI into the controller. I have a  directive that has isolate scope (scope: {}), where I am passing searchTerms, the results object and both the autocomplete and search functions. I'm using ngRoute for now because I'm trying to keep this simple until I have it working - its only 2 pages.

**HTML Snippet**

```
<search-results ng-model="searchTerms" website-urls="page" results="results" uib-typeahead="query for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search($item)"></search-results>
```

**Light Bulb moment, maybe**
As I continue to learn more about directives, I think I just solved the problem. I had all this working initially without the use of a directive. Using routes, templates and controllers. I should just be able to use my current controller in my directive, right?

The only reason why I want to use a directive is because it seems to be the best option when AngularJS is used in combination with a CMS.

Am I on the right track now?

Comment: A Fiddle or more code samples might help more I guess. Unable to understand clearly :( The part where you assign the service 'searchTerms' to scope and then watch it to assign back to itself ? Sorry but I think this question needs more information.

Comment: @pathrik, I assign it to $scope in the controller and then I $watch for changes, which are assigned back to the service, so that searchTerms can be portable and used on various future parts of the app.

Comment: Sorry, I guess i still don't understand clearly. More complete code might be helpful.

Comment: So I'm a little confused on why you are trying to pass the service to directive via the scope. Do you just want the values that are in the service?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to display the entered searchterms from your homepage on your result page?

Comment: @KentCooper, yes, I want the value of seachTerms(ngModel) to be passed, maybe I'm going about this the wrong way - any ideas?

Comment: @Danscho well yes, it seems that I able to pass the value of searchTerms, but what is NOT happening, is any search functionality - no results are displayed.

Comment: What happens if you change your input to say ng-model="terms" searchTerms="terms"? Also a plunkr would be nice.

Comment: @MikeCheel I tried and it stops it from working :(, thanks for the trying tho.

Comment: Just did a console.log for searchTerms, and it comes out as undefined in my directive file.

Comment: Can you show the html snippet where the searchResults directive is being loaded? The <search-results ...></search-results> part.

Comment: @chris sure, just added snippet, thanks for having a look

Answer (score 0):

After further reading (and understanding), it seems that I can use the controller I already have in my directive and that should solve this problem quite nicely. I will post results after completing and testing it.

Comment: And just for future reference Angular services are singletons you would need to pass it into the scope of your directive to get the value you can inject the service into your directive and the values on the service would be available from within the directive.